# How to search inside an uploaded document?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to find a way to search inside the uploaded files.
If a user uploads a pdf, CSV, word, etc... to the system, the user should be able to search inside the uploaded file with the keywords.
Is there a way for that or a library?

or

maybe should I save the file as a text inside a model and search from that?

I will appreciate all kind of reccommendation.

Comment: check the kind of file and read in the file using the necessary package.

Answer (score 1):

Well If you save the file text in the db and then search it seems to be a practical idea.
But I feel there mi8 be decrease in performance.
Or maybe you If you upload the file in S3 bucket and use the presigned url to generate the file from the db once uploaded and then perform search operation.

Comment: Nice, I was assuming the same thing.